# TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Tags: python-3.x, django

так выглядит структура проекта

---

### [image: так выглядит структура проекта]

Хочу чтобы на главной странице показывался отдельный шаблон, для этого создал файл views.py.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def hello(request):
    return render(request, 'ex3/main_list.html')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import hello

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', hello)
]
```

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

всё это выводит мне ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я не понимаю, что мне делать с ней. Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ex3/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```